# Doubly List Copy Constructor: How different is it from a Singly List Copy Constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list

I just finished working on a singly list copy constructor, and I'm now headed to making a doubly list copy constructor. Can anyone tell me how different it is from a singly list constructor, cause I'm conflicted between starting afresh for my doubly linked list copy constructor or copying my singly list copy constructor. How should I go about this?

If it helps, here is my copy constructor from my singly linked list:

```
        List(const List &copying) : head(NULL)
        {
            Node* cur = copying.head;
            int size = copying.size();
            Node* end = NULL;
            for(int q = 0; q < size; q++)
            {
                Node* n = new Node;
                n->value = cur->value;
                if (head == NULL)
                {
                    head = n;
                    end = head;
                }
                else
                {
                    end->next = n;
                    end = n;
                }
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            end->next = NULL;
        }
```

Any and all input is welcome. Thanks everyone :-)

Comment: Your singly linked list copy constructor will blow up if you are copying from an empty list.  First rule of linked-lists:  Never have special cases.  `Node** target = &head; for (Node* cur = copying.head; cur; cur=cur-next) { Node* n = new Node(cur->value); *target = n; target = &(n->next); } *target = nullptr;`

Comment: What exactly would "blow up" mean @MartinBonner? I'm actually new to programming in c++.

Comment: @PeterG That link was not about copy constructors. I had checked it, but it didn't answer my query regarding copy constructors for doubly linked lists.

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't notice your comment here before replying below.  When the list is empty, you never set `end` to anything other than NULL, and then you write to `end->next` - which will (with luck) cause an access violation.  (If it doesn't, you are probably running on an embedded device, and have just splatted the interrupt vector somewhere.)

Comment: I see, @MartinBonner. I missed that glitch in my code :(. Thanks for clarifying it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to store the previous node (prv).
Assuming Your Node has prv as data member.

```
List(const List &copying) : head(NULL)
{
    Node* cur = copying.head;
    int size = copying.size();
    Node* end = NULL;
    Node* prv = NULL:
    for(int q = 0; q < size; q++)
    {
        Node* n = new Node;
        n->value = cur->value;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            end = head;
        }
        else
        {
            end->next = n;
            end = n;
        }
        n->prv=prv;
        prv=n;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    end->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Well you've reproduced the bug - try copying a zero length list!

Comment: @MartinBonner isn't that what the if `(head == NULL) { head = n; end = head; }` would accomplish?

Comment: @NewbietoProgramming: No.  If size is zero, the for loop is never executed, and we have `end = NULL; {} end->next = NULL;` It's the final write through `end` that kills us in the empty loop case.  (You *can* fix this with a test if `end` is NULL, but a better fix is shown in my comment to the question.)

Comment: @user1438832 Wow, only 4 extra lines of code did the job! I was expecting it to be more than that!